# firestore update or add successful status

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Is there a status in firestore to check if the adding or updating of data is successful? I have this code below :

```
const result = await addFood(foodObj);

if (result.status)?
```

Answer (score 2):

The `then` will contains the sucess response else if it has failed. catch block will be executed.

```
await ref.setData(data).then((doc) {
      print("doc save successful");
    }).catchError((error) {
      print("doc save error");
      print(error);
    });
```